# Best way to sort multiple ranges in Excel via Python

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I'm looking to try to sort some "tables" in Excel via Python as if I were doing it manually (that is selecting the range and then clicking sort). These are the tables I'm talking about:

[image]

Each of these cells in the tables excluding the names contains a formula such as a `vlookup` into a different sheet holding all of the data such as how many sales John Doe has made today and how many has John Doe made overall.

I would like to sort these tables via Python by the condition of sales from highest to lowest and then if sales numbers are the same then by conversion rate highest to lowest.

This is what I want to end up with:

[image]

I would like to keep the conditional formatting if possible or if possible add it into the code.

I have experimented sorting with Pandas however it has deleted the conditional formatting and has changed my conversion percentages into decimals.

This is the code I experimented with Pandas.

Sheet1 is where the tables are located, Sheet2 is the where the call numbers are pulling from, Sheet3 is where the sales numbers are being pulled from.

```
import pandas as pd

xl = pd.ExcelFile('file.xlsx')
df = xl.parse("Sheet1")
df = df.sort_values(by=["Sales", "Conversion"])
df2 = xl.parse("Sheet2")
df3 = xl.parse("Sheet3")

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False)
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet2', index=False)
df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet3', index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: You might consider openpyxl or xlsxwriter directly, instead of using pandas.

Comment: @BigBen I have looked into openpyxl however I read somewhere that it doesn't actually sort the table

Comment: If it were me, I would create the 'raw' tables in a separate sheet, then use the SORTBY() function (if you have it in your version) to create the formatted and sorted tables. Then everything would update automatically. And not use Python at all. Or indeed look into PowerQuery to filter and sort the data from another location in the workbook.

Comment: @DS_London trying to make my life easier by automating somethings lol; run so many reports everyday